# Scala-IDE - how to navigate to inferred type

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, scala-ide

I'm wondering whether in Scala-IDE is there possibility to jump from inferred value/variable to type of this variable. I can only see type information in tooltip while hovering over variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`T` to find type that you see in tooltip.

Comment: I know that. But I want to omit this step. You can even hold mouse cursor for a while over tooltip, and you are able to copy (ctrl+c) type name, but this is not the point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly better workaround in the current nightlies of Scala IDE.
A feature has been added to make inferred types explicit.

Put the caret on the line declaring the val/var and use `Ctrl+1`. You should see the quick fix `Add explicit type ...`. Then you can navigate to the type.

If you have a good idea on how to improve the UI to make this navigation possible, please [open a feature request](http://scala-ide.org/docs/community.html).

Comment: What version of scala-ide you are talking about? 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: It is a new feature in 4.x.